# Common HTML template for multiple components with added individual code from component

Tags: html, angular

In an app there are some differ components, which refer to a common template by using the same url:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'JG-Percentage',
  templateUrl: '../../../../htmlStructure/htmlBaseTemplate/TemplateVarlist.component.svg',
  styleUrls: ['./Percentage.component.sass']
})
```

So far so good, also by using angular two-way binding: `[(ngModel)]='variable.varLabel'`.

But now on some components needs some additional small html code, also with angular two-way binding:    `[(ngModel)]='variable.inputStr'`.

How to inject this added html code into the common template? Or may two html files can be related together to one component?

Thanks for help.

The example is shown on https://angulartool.de

Comment: Hey JuergenG.
I'm not sure I got your question.
What you need to achive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to inject this added html code into the common template? ...

You can add `*ngIf="isCustom"` on the additional HTML and use `[(ngModel)]` inside as  you wish. Then in all the Typescript component classes using this same HTML template file, you can have the boolean property for `isCustom` (or whatever variable name). `isCustom` will be true for the component classes that use the additional HTML and false for those that do not.

If you are using `[(ngModel)]` directly on the additional HTML and in case Angular complains that you can't use `ngModel` together with `*ngIf` (as is the case with `*ngFor`), you can wrap this additional HTML in an `ng-container` and add `*ngIf` there instead.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isCustom">
  <div [(ngModel)]="variable.inputStr">additional HTML</div>
</ng-container>
```

> ... Or may two html files can be related together to one component?

A Typescript component class can have **only one** HTML file. Two HTML files can't be linked to the same typescript component class. (Though it is not the case with styles. One component class can have multiple style files).

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but then I have a common template, which will have for each "special case" extra html code ans e-g *ngswitch. This is acceptable, if only few differ changes are needed, but I expect some more cases.

Comment: It can still work with multiple cases and ngSwitch, just make sure each component class has the value of the ngSwitch variable. Also, if at that point it was not still enough then consider creating an AngularModule then use `RouterModule.forChild` with those components. Maybe have a general component for the non-changing HTML and its router-oultet will be for each child. Then each child component will have its own HTML. If the HTML gets small, then you can use `template` instead of `templateUrl` in the `@Component` decorator, that is HTML inside typescript file. let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have solved now with a string template build by the component.ts and given as innerHTML to the template via a addHtml:string. `<ng-container *ngIf="!!addHTML">
  <div >{{addHTMLerg}}</div>
</ng-container>`Then I have a *ngif="!!addHtml". By this all components must have addHtml:string='', but this is O.K.  You may see this behavior on https://angulartool.de/KehlnahtDicke, depending on the reust T1=300, T2=15,5 in the green field.

Comment: Oh yes another template was another option. Glad that you've solved it. The page you linked is returning 404. But the home page of angulartool.de is a great one. That is for the formulas.

Comment: Oh thanks for the feedback of the 404 error. I added the needed .htaccess file to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have two html templates for one component by have a additinal child component.
The  child component do nothing more as to extends the Component for which the second template is needed.

The complete code excample with comments is shown on stackblitz and the related extended component is the No.3.

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7oeube?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts**